# Find the area of the following region D on $xy$-plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the following region D on $xy$-plane bounded the curve given by the following equation in polar coordinates:

$r = 2 - 2 \sin \theta \ \ \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$

Sorry, I'm quite new to multi-variable calculus. 
I'm doing some supplementary exercise and saw this question, I did the natural thing and just find the definite integral of the given equation but the answer I got was 4$ \pi$, I should be getting $6 \pi$. Can anyone show some what are the steps and basic concepts involve here ?

Any help and insights is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should check your course material to see if there's anything on area with *polar curves*. It doens't work like functions given in cartesian coordinates where you integrate
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$
to get the area below the graph of $f$ (I'm leaving out some details). You may find the formula
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_\alpha^\beta r^2 dt$$
for the area enclosed by a polar curve $r=r(t)$ between the rays $t=\alpha$ and $t=\beta$; e.g. check [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Area.html). Using this formula will give you the correct answer $6\pi$.